# Imagemagick's mogrify can't render text

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I'm trying a simple

```
mogrify test.png  -annotate +100+100 '26082015'
```

on a simple image, and no text is rendered.

I also tried:

```
mogrify test.png -font courier -fill black -pointsize 20  -annotate +100+100 "26082015"
```

and

```
mogrify test.png -gravity NorthEast -draw "text 42,80 '26082015'"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

To render a text with `mogrify` use it like this:

```
mogrify [options] input-file
```

Taking one of your examples:

```
mogrify -annotate +100+100 '26082015' test.png
```

Per the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mogrify) the last argument on the command line is the file that needs to be processed. So, first you specify options and after that filename.